# Is it possible to estimate the Interaction information of three variables without knowing their joint distributions?

Tags: pr.probability, it.information-theory

I want to have a measure of the "synergy" between two players in a game. Each player has its own win ratio (won/played), which I'm modeling as two binomial distributed random variables X and Y. A third binomial distributed variable Z models the win ratio of both players as a team. The three variables are clearly dependent.
The trouble I have is that, AFAIK, the joint distribution of the variables is needed to calculate the joint entropy of the variables, and I have no idea how to get around this.

Comment: You are talking about distributions, but I think you simply mean that there are three numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Douglas. Actually, yes there are three numbers, but I'm assuming they are drawn from three binomial distributions. So if $b(k; n, p) = \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k} $ I'm estimating $p$ with the win ratio, $n$ is the number of matches played, and $k$ the number of matches won.